# Table and figure side by side. Using float, not floatrow, seperate captions

Tags: subfloats, floatrow

I am trying to make tables and figure work side by side with seperate captions, with `float` not `floatrow`.
I use `float` and `subfigure` in a number of places already.

I made a small example with my full preamble.

```
\documentclass[runningheads,a4paper]{llncs}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\newcommand{\itodo}[1]{\todo[inline, color=green!40]{#1}}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\tikzstyle{important line}=[very thick]
\tikzstyle{information text}=[rounded corners,fill=white,inner sep=1ex]

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, multicol, multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \subfigure[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{...}}
  \hspace{.02\textwidth}
  \subfigure[a]{\includegraphics[width=0.24\textwidth]{...}}
  \label{fig:aa}
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}
\begin{floatrow}
\ffigbox
  {\begin{tikzpicture}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }
  {\caption{One}}\label{fig:1}}
\killfloatstyle
\ttabbox
{\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \hline
    column1a & column2a \\
    column1b & column2b \\
    column1c & column2c \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
}
{\caption{2}\label{tab:ss}}
\end{floatrow}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: There is still a `\usepackage{floatrow}` and a `\begin{floatrow}` in your example. Are you going to use it, or not to use?

Comment: That is in there to show the desired effect.

Comment: **subfigure** is obsolete and ought not be used. **subfig** or **subcaption** are alternatives. `\tikzstyle` is deprecated and should be replaced by `\tikzset` (unless you are using a quite old version of PGF/TikZ which is not recommended). Don't load packages more than once. It is a recipe for mysterious, hard-to-diagnose problems whose underlying causes turn out to be annoyingly simple.  When posting examples, only use a non-standard class if it is essential to the question. In that case, please provide a link so that people can obtain the class. Otherwise, use a standard class.

Answer (score 2):

From your question I guess, that you like to have independent numbering figures in tables even if they are partly in the same float:

[image]

Is this, what you like to achieve? The code for above image is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{capt-of}

    \begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hbt]
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-a}
  \caption{figure a}
  \label{fig:a}
\end{figure}
some text
\begin{figure}[hbt]
  \centering
\includegraphics[width=0.2\textwidth]{example-image-b}
  \caption{figure b}
  \label{fig:b}
\end{figure}

some text
\begin{figure}[hbt]
    \begin{minipage}{0.48\hsize}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\hsize]{example-image-c}
  \captionof{figure}{figure c}
  \label{fig:c}
\end{minipage}
    \hfill
\begin{minipage}{0.48\hsize}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
    \hline
    column1a & column2a \\
    column1b & column2b \\
    column1c & column2c \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{table 1}
    \label{tab:1}
\end{minipage}
    \end{figure}

 Regarding to figures \ref{fig:a}, \ref{fig:b}, \ref{fig:c} and table \ref{tab:1} \dots
    \end{document}
```

As you can see, for it I didn't use `float` nor `floatrow`. Desired goal I obtain by use of small package `capt-of`. For `example-image`s I also add package `graphicx`. I'm not familiar with package `llncs`, but I'm sure that it will not interfere to shoved solution.

By the way, in the preamble of your document some packages are load twice ...

Comment: Using `h` for float placement is not recommended. If `h` is specified, LaTeX tries to place the float here even if other options are listed. If it cannot place it here, it changes it to `ht` automatically. So it is kind of misleading to write `h` since it will not always mean here. It is better to say explicitly where else is OK if you want to specify preferred positioning at all. (And, of course, LaTeX will still fall back to `p` if it has to because  it may not be able to place the float either here or at the top of a page.)

Comment: @cfr, thank you for explanation about placement option `h`.  I'm aware about this. Personally I usual add to preamble `\def\fps@figure{hbtp}` (wrapped by `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`) and then don't care about them.